# 301 redirect rule breaks previous rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following `.htaccess` configuration for my two versions of my site (at /oldsite and /newsite respectively):

```
RewriteEngine On

# load newsite if not newsite and not oldsite
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:newsite|oldsite)).*)$ newsite/$1 [NC,L]

# load root if request is oldsite
RewriteRule ^oldsite(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC]

# certain urls need to be loaded in page.php
RewriteRule ^newsite/(products|services|news|pages)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-/]+)$ /newsite/page.php?type=$1&var=$2 

#remove trailing .php
RewriteRule ^newsite/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /newsite/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^newsite/admin/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /newsite/admin/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

I now want to do a bulk 301 redirect for all non-www requests to www and also a 301 redirect to a non-trailing slash url. For example:

- `www.example.com///` -> `www.example.com`
- `example.com/////` -> `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com/somepage//` -> `www.example.com/somepage`

I tried adding the following in different positions in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this breaks previous rules. For example entering `example.com` leads to `www.example.com/newsite`.

The whole config has become a spaghetti of rules and I need to clean these up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your non-www to www redirect should go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file. Otherwise, a request for the non-www host that triggers an internal rewrite (eg. to `newsite/$1`) could get converted to a redirect, which appears to be what is happening here (when you are redirected to `www.example.com/newsite`). As a general rule, redirects should always come before rewrites. There should then be no conflict.

> `www.example.com///` -> `www.example.com`

Strictly speaking there is always 1 slash at the end of the hostname (or rather, at the *start of the URL-path*), it's just that the browser often omits it in the address bar. This is different to slashes at the *end of the URL-path*, which can be omitted entirely.

```
# Remove multiple slashes anywhere in the URL-path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive simply checks for multiple slashes anywhere in the URL-path (of the *initial request*). The redirect then relies on the fact that Apache automatically truncates multiple slashes in the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and uses this (`$1` backreference) in the *substitution*. This will also reduce a request for `www.example.com////<whatever>////<something>////` to `www.example.com/<whatever>/<something>/`.

Then, to remove the trailing slash at the end (or any number of trailing slashes):

```
# Remove trailing slash(es)
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The redirect works, but putting something like `example.com///` doesn't remove trailing slashes. It takes me to my 404 page. Here is my whole config after entering your suggested changes: http://pastebin.com/U6aVmJC7

Comment: The directives _should_ have removed the trailing slashes on `example.com///`. Make sure your browser cache is clear. (You'll still need your original www redirect at the top of your script, as mentioned above.) I've updated my answer to allow for the more general scenario - reducing slashes _anywhere_ in the URL. As far as your server is concerned, it should matter whether the request is for `example.com/` or `example.com///` - they both resolve to the same thing. Does `example.com/` result in a 404? According to your directives this would be rewritten to `/newsite/` - is this valid?